# How to fit array data in canvas function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image: This is final output.]

```
var dps =[]; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'data.php',
        success:function(response){
            var result= JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(result); //var count = Object.keys(result).length;
            //console.log(count);

            for(var i=0; i<result.day.length;i++){
              dps.push({"label":result.day[i], "y":result.amount[i]});
            }
            console.log(dps);
            DrawHigh(dps);
            //DrawCanvas(dps);
        }
    });
});
function DrawHigh(data){
    Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
    Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {
        xAxis: {
          categories: , 
          title: {
              enabled: true,
              text: '<b>Purchase</b>',
              style: {
                  fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
            }
         },
       legend: {
          enabled: false
            },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
            },
      series: [{
          data: ,
           }]
     });
}
```

This is my code. I want to render var dps =[] array data to draw Highchart. Because in highchart we have to put data in series, now same data how i put in series.

[image: This is the output of console.log(dps); These are the values contain by dps array.] I want to draw this dps array data, but how to use this data to draw Highchart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this basic example (on JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) from their [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic):

```
dps.push({"label":result.day[i], "y":result.amount[i]});
```

should be:

```
dps.push({"name":result.day[i], "data":result.amount[i]});
```

then you can pass the `dps` array to the `DrawHigh(data)` function.

```
series: data  // Where data is dps, an array of objects having the right property names.
```

---

**EDIT**

In your ajax success callback, replace the `for` loop by this:

```
var xAxisCat = [];
var seriesData = [];

for(var i=0; i<result.day.length;i++){
  xAxisCat.push(result.day[i])
  seriesData.push(result.amount[i]);
}
```

Then send those two arrays to HightCharts like this:

```
var xAxis = {categories: xAxisCat};
var series = [{data: seriesData, , name: "My graph"}];

DrawHigh(xAxis, series);
```

In `function DrawHigh(xAxis, series){`, which now has two arguments,  just do `xAxis: xAxis` and `series: series`. The data is correctly formed to just pass it like this.

Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vJdveZ?editors=1010) with the right result, but using *"simulated"* data (since I can't access your `data.php`) that the loop I suggest above produce.

Comment: provide me your mail id, i will mail you.

Comment: what you are give ans here is not what i want.

Comment: Well take the time you need to define what you really want... And write it here.